# Batch update cases - closing cases

Tags: civicase

I was very excited to test out the new capability that you can batch update cases but I'm not sure I'm testing it as intended. I was hoping to be able to use it to close multiple cases at once. Here is what's happeneing:

- Even though I can update the case statuses to a 'closed' status like "Resolved" it doesn't record an activity (with the date that the case was closed).
- If I add the case end date to the profile, a undefined notice pops up on the batch edit screen and I can only select today's date. Notice: Undefined index: formatType in CRM_Utils_Date::addDateMetadataToField() (line 1878 of /srv/buildkit/build/dmaster/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Date.php).
- If I do process the update with today's date, I don't see anywhere that the date is referenced (aside from being able to search by end date, I don't see a reference inside the case itself.)

I'm assuming I'm expecting too much (mixing capabilities)? It is after all technically updating the case status and date.

(While I am currently in Civi 5.5.3 - I verified this behavior is also on the dmaster demo site.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like either it was unfinished or the usual tracking was maybe intentionally left out. More info here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11411

Comment: Thank you for the link, it does appear that they built it to mirror the typical batch update using a profile approach. In our implementation, updating the case status without recording some sort of activity is problematic but for others, of course, this may not be the case. Overall the added capability to batch update case information is great!

Comment: I agree it's a little bit problematic. One of the original goals of CiviCase was to get close to HIPPA compliance. Although I believe there's a move in core towards a different logging mechanism that might eventually apply to CiviCase too, so maybe the batch action will get automatically included in that. I'm not familiar with that yet.